# Testing CORS locally

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

I have an Api that accepts CORS requests.

I was trying to test this application by remapping my `hosts` file in `c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` as follows:

`127.0.0.1 localhost.mydomain.com`

So I hosted my calling application off:

`localhost.mydomain.com`

And my Api off:

`localhost`

And found that the Api call returned `Error: Access denied.` in IE10

However in Chrome the same configuration worked fine.

I then fiddled for some time, I understand that IE10 fully support CORS so was surprised this did not work.

Eventually I got the CORS requests to work with another entry in my hosts file

`127.0.0.1    localapi.mydomain.com`

Is there something specific that stops IE10 being able to call Localhost when on another domain?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just an educated guess: IE has defined security zones that guide, what is allowed and what not. It might be, that `localhost` is placed in the internal, trusted, zone, while the `.com` is placed in the "wild web" zone with fewer permissions. Thus IE might voluntarily cut the connection between both.

Try to place your local domains via "Internet Options" > "Security Zones" in the "internal zone" and see, if this fixes the access problem.